# How to download a (huge) text file using HttpWebRequest with credentials?

Tags: c#, winforms, download, httpwebrequest

I am trying to automate downloading a list of text files from a certain website. The process of downloading a text file is like this:

1. click on a name of the file that opens up a popup window.
2. content is in the popup window // it can be downloaded as a string, but it is too huge to be download using a StreamWriter since I'm experiencing an out of memory exception.
3. right click -> save as.

I would like to download this file with HttpWebRequest.

My code looks like this:

```
string sTmpCookieString = GetGlobalCookies(webBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri);
HttpWebRequest fstRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
fstRequest.Method = "GET";
fstRequest.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
fstRequest.CookieContainer.SetCookies(webBrowser1.Document.Url, sTmpCookieString);
HttpWebResponse fstResponse = (HttpWebResponse)fstRequest.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fstResponse.GetResponseStream());
string sPageData = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();

string sViewState = ExtractInputHidden(sPageData, "__VIEWSTATE");
string sEventValidation = this.ExtractInputHidden(sPageData, "__EVENTVALIDATION");

string sUrl = URL;
HttpWebRequest hwrRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sUrl);
hwrRequest.Method = "POST";
hwrRequest.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();

string sPostData = "__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=" + sViewState + "&__EVENTVALIDATION=" + sEventValidation + "&Name=test" + "&Button1=Button";

byte[] bByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sPostData);
hwrRequest.ContentType = "text/plain";
hwrRequest.CookieContainer.SetCookies(webBrowser1.Document.Url, sTmpCookieString);
hwrRequest.ContentLength = bByteArray.Length;

Stream sDataStream = hwrRequest.GetRequestStream();
sDataStream.Write(bByteArray, 0, bByteArray.Length);
sDataStream.Close();
using (WebResponse response = hwrRequest.GetResponse())
{
    using (sDataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(sDataStream);
        {
            string sResponseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            Byte[] info = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(sResponseFromServer);
            fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
            fs.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

..and I keep getting HTML something looks like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>    

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
<meta content="Microsoft Visual Studio 7.0" name="GENERATOR" />
...
```

I think my question might be unclear at somewhere to someone. Therefore, I will try to explain in detail if somebody points out.

I will appreciate any help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to read the whole response at once:

```
string sResponseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Instead, consider using something like:

```
using (sDataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
    sDataStream.CopyTo(fs, 10000);
    fs.Close();                            
}
```

The second parameter there is the buffer size, you can set it to any reasonable value.

Answer (score 1):

An WebRequest download using the asynchronous version: [WebRequest.GetResponseAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.getresponseasync)

Starting from your `using (WebResponse response = hwrRequest.GetResponse()) { };`
The rest of the code is mostly fine.

Size the Buffer used to download/store you file as required (`132072` bytes here). Don't make it small for no reason.

The destination file is created with [File.Create()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.create) which defaults to `Create New or Overwrite` and `FileShare.None`.

```
using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)await httpRequest.GetResponseAsync())
using (var stream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream()) {
    if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
        try {
            int buffersize = 132072;
            using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(["YourFileName"], buffersize, FileOptions.Asynchronous))
            {
                int read;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[buffersize];
                while ((read = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {
                    await fileStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, read);
                }
            };
        }
        catch (DirectoryNotFoundException dnfex) {
            throw;  //Log, store&notify. Your usual handling.
        }
        catch (PathTooLongException ptlex) {
            throw;  //Same
        }
        catch (IOException ioex) {
            throw;  //Same
        }
    }
};
return ["YourFileName"];
```

Comment: I have a red undeyline here at "resObject" in line resObject.ResourceLenght = fileStream.Position;  I would like to know what resObject indicates.

Comment: Sorry, a leftover. You don't need that. Delete it. Edited.

Comment: I am still getting html instead of content of the page. do you have any idea..?

Comment: I have no idea how that site works. But, looking at the attempted post, there's something that can go wrong. You're trying to fill a WebForm fields, correctly posting the `_VIEWSTATE`. The Post is then performed using plain text. The parameters should be passed `UrlEncoded` (except the `@` when one of parameters is an email address). There's the chance you're getting the page that's returned when the authentication fails. If you can share a sample URL with parameters, I can test it.

Comment: You can encode the post parameters with [WebUtility.UrlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.urlencode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). The `__VIEWSTATE` should be encoded (because of the default padding: the `=` symbol).